# Resolving named services in DryIoc DI-Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef, dryioc

Consider the following two classes:

```
public class Number
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Multiplier
{
    private readonly Number first;
    private readonly Number second;

    public Multiplier(Number first, Number second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int Multiply() => this.first.Value * this.second.Value;
}
```

The class *Multiplier* depends on two instances of *Number*. I want to inject both of them as *named services* using a DryIoc DI-Container. The code to do this looks like this:

```
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterInstance(new Number{Value = 2}, serviceKey:"first");
container.RegisterInstance(new Number{Value = 4}, serviceKey:"second");
container.Register<Multiplier>();

var consumer = container.Resolve<Multiplier>();

Console.WriteLine(consumer.Multiply());
```

This code fails with a *DryIoc.ContainerException* (when calling *Resolve*) since the registered instances can not be resolved to the constructor arguments. My question basically is: Is there any way that allows me to specify which named *serviceKey* should be resolved to which constructor argument?

In MEF I would do the following to achieve this:

```
[Export(typeof(Multiplier))]
public class Multiplier
{
    private readonly Number first;
    private readonly Number second;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Multiplier([Import("first")]Number first, 
                      [Import("second")]Number second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int Multiply() => this.first.Value * this.second.Value;
}
```

and then export the dependencies using the service names:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(someCatalog);
container.ComposeExportedValue("first", new Number{Value = 2});
container.ComposeExportedValue("second", new Number{Value = 4});

var multi = container.GetExport<Multiplier>();
```

How can I do this using DryIoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may reuse the same MEF code with the [DryIoc.MefAttributedModel.dll](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/Extensions/MefAttributedModel.md) extension.

With the DryIoc alone, you need to specify the mapping between the parameter name (or Type, or position) and the `servicKey`:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterInstance(new Number {Value = 2}, serviceKey:"first");
container.RegisterInstance(new Number {Value = 4}, serviceKey:"second");

container.Register<Multiplier>(made: Parameters.Of
    .Name("first",  serviceKey: "first")
    .Name("second", serviceKey: "second"));

var consumer = container.Resolve<Multiplier>();
```

More details here: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/SpecifyDependencyAndPrimitiveValues.md#complete-example-of-matching-the-parameter-name-to-the-service-key